# docker: /opt/docker folder not created

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure my project to dockerize it. I can test it locally in my wsl environment, and it works fine. Inside docker, /opt/docker folder is created, and I can access my application from host machine.

But on dev server, I observe that /opt/docker is not even created.

I am not able to diagnose the root cause. Shouldn't docker behave similarly on all machines?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, no. You shouldn't care about 'docker', how its implemented or what directories it uses. You should only care that it works.

For example, on my WSL installation, I have `/opt/containerd`, not `/opt/docker`.  I think this is because I locally install docker in wsl (because I refuse to use Docker Desktop). It's different again when I deploy to my k8s cluster, which doesn't use docker at all.

You should care about your images and containers. As long as your container runs the same, then the rest is an implementation detail that should be transparent to you.

Comment: so what/where should I actually look for to find the cause? It works fine for in my wsl. Sorry, I am not very well versed with docker.

Comment: @Mandroid you have what one calls a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). You are asking how to debug via a folder on the host machine but failed to describe what you want to debug in the first place. So, what is not working with your container on your server?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. So in my 'docker run' command I have, apart from other options, '-v $pwd/log:/opt/docker/log'. This is for log files. During local testing, I see it working as expected and /opt/docker/log folder generated and log files placed inside it. On jenkins build, deployment fails as no such folder structure is created inside docker. So that's the basic issue.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question. However, the result will be the same. That's not your folder ('/opt/docker') so you shouldn't be touching it. Write your logs somewhere into your home directory -- they're your logs, not docker's.